# how to pass commandline argument include "|" to java program

Tags: java, command-line, arguments

One of the arguments passed to my java program is like this, `ab|cd`. Initially, when I run the java program, like this,

> $ java className ab|cd

it fails, since `|` is interpreted in the linux shell as a pipe symbol. So only `ab` is passed into java program. So I made a second attempt:

> $ java className "ab|cd"

This time, `"ab|cd"` is passed in, but the value includes the double quotes. What the program is really intended to have is `ab|cd`. How can I pass in the correct value without the quotes?

Comment: you can also quote(`"ab|cd"` or `'ab|cd')` the commandline arguments

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the command shell, you can escape out characters using the '\' character.

```
 java className ab\|cd
```

Answer (score 3):

Try (for Linux):

```
$ java className ab\|cd
```

For Windows:

```
java className ab^|cd
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

`"\" is used inorder to nullify the effect of the characters which have special meanings.`

```
java className ab\|cd
```

Answer (score -2):

Maybe try this:

```
arg="ab|cd"
java className $arg
```